# Error during compilation, incompatible argument type

Tags: magento2

Magento 2.2.2

Following is the error I am getting:

I am getting following error on compilation with MGS Store Locator extension:

```
Errors during compilation:
    MGS\StoreLocator\Controller\Adminhtml\Locator\Save
            Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context. Actual type: \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context; File:
  /home/nginx/domains/mydomain.com/public/app/code/MGS/StoreLocator/Controller/Adminhtml/Locator/Save.php

    MGS\StoreLocator\Controller\Adminhtml\Locator\Edit
            Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context. Actual type: \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context; File:/home/nginx/domains/mydomain.com/public/app/code/MGS/StoreLocator/Controller/Adminhtml/Locator/Edit.php
```

**/home/nginx/domains/mydomain.com/public/app/code/MGS/StoreLocator/Controller/Adminhtml/Locator/Save.php**

```
            namespace MGS\StoreLocator\Controller\Adminhtml\Locator;

            use MGS\StoreLocator\Model\StoreFactory;
            use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
            use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

            class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action {

                protected $_storeFactory;
                protected $_coreRegistry;
                protected $_storeManager;
                protected $_filesystem;
                protected $_fileUploaderFactory;

                public function __construct(Context $context, 
                        StoreFactory $storeFactory, 
                        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry, 
                        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
                        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
                        \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $fileUploaderFactory) {
                    parent::__construct($context);
                    $this->_storeFactory = $storeFactory;
                    $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
                    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
                    $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;
                    $this->_fileUploaderFactory = $fileUploaderFactory;
                }

                /**
                 * @return void
                 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
                 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
                 */
                public function execute() {
                    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
                    if (!$data) {
                        $this->_redirect('locator/*/');
                        return;
                    }

                    $model = $this->_objectManager->create('MGS\StoreLocator\Model\Store');
                    if (!empty($data['id'])) {
                        $model->load($data['id']);
                    }
                    if (!empty($data['id']) && $model->isObjectNew()) {
                        $this->messageManager->addError(__('This Locator no longer exists.'));
                        $this->_redirect('locator/*/');
                        return;
                    }

                    // Store logo Image upload
                    if(isset($_FILES['image']['name']) && $_FILES['image']['name'] != '') {
                        /** @var $uploader \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader */
                        $uploader = $this->_fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'image']);
                        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
                        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                        $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
                        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
                        $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                        if($uploader->checkAllowedExtension($ext)) {
                            $path = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)
                                    ->getAbsolutePath('mgs_storelocator/');
                            $uploader->save($path);

                            $fileName = $uploader->getUploadedFileName();
                            if ($fileName) {
                                $data['image'] = 'mgs_storelocator'.$fileName;
                            }
                        } else {
                            $this->messageManager->addError(__('Disallowed file type.'));
                            return $this->redirectToEdit($model, $data);
                        }
                    } else {
                        if(isset($data['image']['delete']) && $data['image']['delete'] == 1) {
                            $data['image'] = '';
                        } else {
                            unset($data['image']);
                        }
                    }

                    $model->setData($data);
                    try {
                        $model->setStoreIds($this->getRequest()->getParam('stores', []));
                        $model->save();
                        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('You saved the store locator.'));
                        $this->_getSession()->setLocator(false);
                        $back = $this->getRequest()->getParam('back', false);
                        if($back == 'edit') {
                            return $this->_redirect('locator/*/edit', ['id' => $model->getId(), '_current' => true, 'active_tab' => '']);
                        }
                        $this->_redirect('locator/*/');
                    } catch (\Exception $e) {
                        $messages = $e->getMessages();
                        $this->messageManager->addMessages($messages);
                        $this->redirectToEdit($model, $data);
                    }
                }

                /**
                 * @param MGS\StoreLocator\Model\StoreFactory $model
                 * @param array $data
                 * @return void
                 */
                protected function redirectToEdit($model, array $data) {
                    $this->_getSession()->setLocator($data);
                    $arguments = $model->getId() ? ['id' => $model->getId()] : [];
                    $arguments = array_merge($arguments, ['_current' => true, 'active_tab' => '']);
                    $this->_redirect('locator/*/edit', $arguments);
                }

            }
```

**/home/nginx/domains/mydomain.com/public/app/code/MGS/StoreLocator/Controller/Adminhtml/Locator/Edit.php**

```
          /**
             *
             * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
             * See COPYING.txt for license details.
             */

            namespace MGS\StoreLocator\Controller\Adminhtml\Locator;

            use MGS\StoreLocator\Model\StoreFactory;
            use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

            class Edit extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action {

                protected $_storeFactory;
                protected $_coreRegistry;

                public function __construct(Context $context, StoreFactory $storeFactory, \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry) {
                    parent::__construct($context);
                    $this->_storeFactory = $storeFactory;
                    $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
                }

                /**
                 * @return $this
                 */
                protected function _initAction()
                {
                    $this->_view->loadLayout();
                    $this->_addBreadcrumb(
                        __('Store Locator'),
                        __('Store Locator')
                    )->_addBreadcrumb(
                        __('Edit'),
                        __('Edit')
                    );
                    return $this;
                }

                /**
                 * @return void
                 */
                public function execute() {
                    $storeId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
                    /** @var \Magento\User\Model\User $model */
                    $model = $this->_storeFactory->create();

                    if ($storeId) {
                        $model->load($storeId);
                        if (!$model->getId()) {
                            $this->messageManager->addError(__('This Locator no longer exists.'));
                            $this->_redirect('adminhtml/*/');
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    // Restore previously entered form data from session
                    $data = $this->_session->getLocator(true);
                    if (!empty($data)) {
                        $model->setData($data);
                    }
                    $this->_coreRegistry->register('locator', $model);
                    if (isset($storeId)) {
                        $breadcrumb = __('Edit Store');
                    } else {
                        $breadcrumb = __('New Store');
                    }
                    $this->_initAction()->_addBreadcrumb($breadcrumb, $breadcrumb);
                    $this->_view->getPage()->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Stores'));
                    $this->_view->getPage()->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend($model->getId() ? __("Edit Store '%1'", $model->getName()) : __('New Store'));
                    $this->_view->renderLayout();
                }

            }
```

Can anyone please tell where is the issue?

Comment: Check the answer, Afaq

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Error says you are injecting the wrong classes in constructor

> Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context. Actual type: \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context; File:

Replace

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
```

With

```
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
```